# How can I return a 404 error page when user hits a wrong url in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

Hi I have the urls like the following, here if the user hits urls which are not in my urls.py file then I need to return a 404 Error page how to do it?

```
urlpatterns = patterns(

                        '',
                        url(r'login$', auth.onLogin),
                        url(r'logout$', auth.onLogout),
                        ......
                      )
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just prepare `404.html` template and set `DEBUG=False` in your `settings.py`

Comment: on this site it is explained as well ;) http://www.pressthered.com/redirecting_to_a_404_page_in_django/

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want a custom 404 page, you just need to set the 404 handler adding in your main urls.py :

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_404_view'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Answer (score 0):

Create a 404.html file in your template folder

add this code to your view

> ```
> from django.shortcuts import render
>
> def handler404(request):
>     return render(request, ’404.html’)
> ```

and in urls.py

> handler404 = ‘mysite.views.handler404′

Comment: Remember turn off the DEBUG to False.